# Is it possible to kick off two different cloud build which are based on subscription to same topic?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

currently i have a cloud-build application which is being kicked off by a pub-sub trigger , subscribing to eg. topic1
I would like to know if i can kick off another cloud-build application from subscribing to the same topic. Is there a way to configure the message (or the trigger) so that if message1 is published to topic1, then cloudbuild1 is kicked off, and if message2 is published to topic1, then cloudbuild2 is kicked off?
Kind regards
marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a subscription on a topic, all the published messages in the topic are replicated in each subscription.

Therefore, if you have TOPIC and Sub1 and Sub2, if you publish 1 message in TOPIC, you will have this message in Sub1 and Sub2.

---

However, you can set up a [filter on messages when you create a subscription](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/filtering). You can set this filter only at the creation and you can't update it later. You need to delete and recreate the subscription if you want to update the filter.

In addition, you can filter only on message attributes, not on the message body content.

Therefore, with filter, think wisely your filter from the beginning and when you publish a message in TOPIC, add attributes that allow your to route the messages to the correct subscription.

Comment: How do you assign a manually created topic/subscription to Cloud Build?

Comment: You can use a PubSub trigger https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-pubsub-triggers

Comment: @guillaume, it seems there is a catch22 when creating triggers for cloud builds. Once you subscribe  to  a topic from cloudbuild trigger, gcp creates a subscription automatically.. but you can't edit that subscription anymore, and therefore you can setup a filter. The filter works if you create subscription from pubsub... but from cloudbuild you can only subscribe to a topic.  Will have to find an alternative solution..  thanks

Comment: My bad, there is a filter field, but it's not on PubSub attributes but on Build attribute.